# Send CTRL+SHIFT+4 keystroke in batch script

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a batch file that will automatically enter a username and password into a program (which works). Now I need to extend the code to simulate pressing `CTRL+SHIFT+4` (the number above the letters).

I tried by adding 
`WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("^+4");` to the file, but nothing happened.. But it could be that those SendKeys are for VBS only, I'm not sure..

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
start "" "C:\Program Files\Pelco\OpsCenter\OpsCenter.exe"
timeout /t 5 /nobreak >nul
set "username=administratie"
set "password=administratie"
CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" "%username%{tab}%password%{enter}"
timeout /t 5 /nobreak >nul
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("^+4");
goto :EOF

@end
```

Comment: yes.you can use Wscript object only in jscript or vbscript.You can check this [sendkeys.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/sendKeys.bat) to see if it will do the thing.

Comment: @npocmaka, I'm not sure what you sent me :P I added the rest of my code. It first opens the software, waits 5 seconds, enters the username and password, waits another 5 seconds and then needs to hit `CTRL+SHIFT+4`

Comment: `WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("^+4");` should be after `@end` I think....

Comment: @npocmaka, I moved it around, but still nothing

Comment: Maybe the [`SendInput()` function](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/3qk9mc/keyboard_keypress_script/) from user32.dll could be used as an alternative to `SendKeys`?  Don't ask me how to modify it to combine three keys with keydown before sending keyup though.